# Independence among order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Given i.i.d uniform variables $X_1, ..., X_n \sim U[0,1]$, is it true that the event $X_i \leq \min_{k \in [i-1]} X_k$ is independent of $X_j \leq \min_{k \in [j-1]} X_k$ for any $i > j$?

The answer seems to be yes through symmetry: $\Pr(X_i \leq \min_{k \in [i-1]} X_k | X_j \leq \min_{k \in [j-1]} X_k) = \Pr(X_i \leq \min_{k \in [i-1]} X_k | X_l \leq \min_{k \in [j-1]} X_k)$ for any $l \in [j-1]$, but I don't have a rigorous proof.

Also, if the above is true, it seems then that this statement is true regardless of the distribution of $X_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setting.** Let $(X_i)_{i\in[n]}$ be i.i.d. random variables having a continuous distribution. Then $X_i$'s are all distinct with probability one. Hence, we can define a random permutation $\pi:[n]\to[n]$ satisfying

$$ \pi(i) = k \quad\iff\quad \text{$X_i$ is the $k$th largest among $X_1,\ldots,X_n$}, $$

or equivalently,

$$ X_{\pi^{-1}(1)} > X_{\pi^{-1}(2)} > \ldots > X_{\pi^{-1}(n)}. $$

Now by the exchangeability, it is easy to prove that $\pi$ has the uniform distribution over the set of all permutations on $[n]$.

**Analysis.** By noting that $X_i < X_j \iff \pi(i) < \pi(j)$, we have

$$ A_i
:= \Bigl\{ X_i \leq \min_{k\in[i-1]} X_k \Bigr\}
= \Bigl\{ X_i = \min_{k\in[i]} X_k \Bigr\}
= \{ \pi(i) = \min \pi([i]) \}. $$

Then we have to check whether $A_i$ and $A_j$ are independent whenever $i \neq j$. To this end, we note that, given $A_i$ and $\pi(i) = p$, the restriction $\pi|_{[j]}$ can assume any $j$-permutation of $\{p+1, \ldots, n\}$ equally likely. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(A_j \mid A_i, \pi(i) = p) = \frac{1}{j} = \mathbf{P}(A_j).
\end{align*}

and we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(A_j \mid A_i)
&= \sum_{p \in [n]} \mathbf{P}(A_j \mid A_i, \pi(i) = p) \mathbf{P}(\pi(i) = p \mid A_i) \\
&= \sum_{p \in [n]} \mathbf{P}(A_j) \mathbf{P}(\pi(i) = p \mid A_i) \\
&= \mathbf{P}(A_j).
\end{align*}

This proves that $A_i$ and $A_j$ are independent.

**Experiment.** The below code verifies $\mathbf{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = \mathbf{P}(A_i)\mathbf{P}(A_j)$ for $n = 8$, $i = 6$, and $j = 3$:

[image: Experiment]

We can play with the values of $n, i, j$, but of course, we will always get $\texttt{True}$ as we have proved.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will look through the proof carefully. Just a quick question in the meantime, what is the software you use to empirically test independence?

Comment: @student_t I used Mathematica :)

Comment: Really thank you for your great answer @SangchulLee. If possible, could you please point out the fallacy in the reasoning that "if $A_j$ does not happen, then $X_i$ has one fewer opponent to be smaller than, and intuitively $A_i$ is more likely to happen"? This is my intuitive feeling when I read the question, but it seems wrong as you rigorously proved.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be "yes, they are independent" as Sangchul proved. Really sorry for my original answer which is wrong.

Below is my original wrong answer.

---

Fix $i > j$ and fix $X_k, k \in [j-1]$,
we want to check whether
$\Pr((X_i \leq \min_{i' \in [i-1]} X_{i'}) \land (X_j \leq \min_{j' \in [j-1]} X_{j'})) = \Pr(X_i \leq \min_{i' \in [i-1]} X_{i'}) \Pr(X_j \leq \min_{j' \in [i-1]} X_{j'}).$

It is easy to see that
$\Pr(X_j \leq \min_{j' \in [i-1]} X_{j'}) = \min_{j' \in [j-1]} X_{j'}$
(assuming uniform variables).
Similarly,
$\Pr(X_i \leq \min_{i' \in [i-1]} X_{i'}) = \min_{i' \in [i-1]} X_{i'}$,
where
\begin{align}
\min_{i' \in [i-1]} X_{i'} = 
\begin{cases}
    \min_{j' \in [j-1]} X_{j'},& \text{if } X_{t} > \min_{j' \in [j-1]} X_{j'}, \forall j \leq t \leq i - 1\\
    \min_{j \leq t \leq i - 1} X_t, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

<s>We can see that if $X_j \leq \min_{j' \in [j-1]} X_{j'}$, then
it rules out the possibility that
$X_j > \min_{j' \in [j-1]} X_{j'}$ 
and thus reduce
$\Pr(X_i \leq \min_{i' \in [i-1]} X_{i'})$.</s>

Comment: Hmm...it's unclear why the last line follows if by assumption $X_{k}$ for $k \in [j-1]$ is assumed to be fixed?

Comment: I think my answer was wrong... Really sorry for that...