# Conditional probability ranking

Tags: probability

My friend and I are discussing the following problem:

> Adam, Bob, Charlie, and Dave are dividing a sum of money between themselves. Does
> knowing that Bob received more money than Adam, increase, decrease, or
> not affect the probability of whether Charlie received more money than
> Adam?

I think that knowing that Bob received more money than Adam means that Adam received a relatively small portion, so this *increases* the probability that Charlie received more money than Adam.

However, my friend says that knowing that Bob received more money than Adam means that Bob received a relatively large portion, reducing the overall amount of money left "up for grabs" by Charlie, so this *decreases* the probability that Charlie received more money than Adam.

Who's reasoning is correct, and why?

Comment: What is the overall probability space? How is the total money divided?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the money is distributed in a "fair" and uniform way, then we can have closed-form probabilities.
Specifically, WLOG, we assume the total quantity of money is $1$, and each person $X \in \{A, B, C, D\}$ draws a random number in $M_X \in [0, 1]$ independently, uniformly at random.
The final amount of money the person $X$ gets is $M_X / \sum_{X' \in \{A, B, C, D\}} M_{X'}$.

Define two events:

- $A_1: M_B > M_A$
- $A_2: M_C > M_A$

Then the problem becomes "What is the relation between $\Pr[A_2]$ and $\Pr[A_2 | A_1]$?"

Due to uniformity and independence, we have
$$\Pr[A_1] = \Pr[A_2] = 0.5,$$
and
$$\Pr[A_1 \land A_2] = \Pr[M_A = \min \{M_A, M_B, M_C\}] = 1/3.$$
This implies that
$$\Pr[A_2 | A_1] = \frac{\Pr[A_1 \land A_2]}{\Pr[A_1]} < \frac{\Pr[A_1] \Pr[A_2]}{\Pr[A_1]} = \Pr[A_2].$$

---

A related question: [Independence among order statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672973)